# Bootstrap tour scroll is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, scroll, bootstrap-tour

I'm using Bootstrap tour its working fine in desktop but in mobile specially in iphone. When tour starts it don't allow user to scroll window manually. When we try to scroll window it pull it back on same position. But i wanna allow user to scroll window. Any solution ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Let us suppose i just start a tour in mobile and its giving introduction for any element which present in header means at the top part of webpage. i wanna scroll my page down without close my tour. So, It don't allow page to move down but i wanna allow it to move down. And i'm using bootstrap-tour plugin.